# OctoberCms Backend not working in subfolder Apache

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I am install a new project of the OctoberCMS in my VPS in a subfolder, example, /var/www/myCMS/ (here this my installation of the OctoberCMS).

When I access my site by domain example: www.mydomain.com/myCMS/ I having a image of the welcome demo, picture bottom:

[image]

But which accessing the Backend (www.mydomain.com/myCMS/backend I have this error:

[image]

Any solution?

My system is:
- Apache2
- Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

sometime default `apache` installation is not come with mode rewrite enabled( as you described its your vpn)

so you need to enabled rewrite module manually
use this 2 commands to `enable` `rewrite module` and `restart apache`

```
a2enmod rewrite

service apache2 restart
```

then just check that your directory have `.htaccess` in order to redirect all request to the `index.php`

in your `apache server` you need this things

```
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    # this is needed to work .htaccess
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for support, but, the module rewrite already is active. Inside the folder /myCMS/ already have too the .htaccess, any other solution? Thanks!

Comment: is it possible that you can share your url

Comment: hmm seems nothing works except root `https://panel.4tech.mobi/painel/demo/ajax` also not working and to me it seems related to `.htacccess` and in your apache config it should be `AllowOverride All` is it all set after this you need to `restart` apache once. can you recheck that thing once

Comment: or better you can attach its content in your question :) apache config for directory `../../..etc../http`  and `.htaccess` content

Comment: to check if you `.htaccess` it working or not you can type `jibrish` in it and then check `url` error should change to the `500 internal server error 500` , if we get this then your `htacess` is in use otherwise not.

Comment: Hardik thanks for support!!!! I made the configuration in the 000-default.conf file on my server.....  

<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

AllowOverride All

Order allow,deny

allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: Do I replace current configuration for yours?

Comment: no i guess its not needed as your config looks ok, did you try to check that `.htaccess` make intentional typo and check site

Comment: Hardik... problem solved... The problem is that I changed the wrong file, in the version of apache 2.4 the configuration must be done in the path /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Thanks very much for support!

Answer (score 0):

In case any of the already mentioned methods don't work check your project directory if you have .htaccess file in case if you are using apache server else create one sudo nano .htaccess or sudo vim .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

##
## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
##
# RewriteBase /

##
## Black list protected files
##
RewriteRule ^themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm /index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^uploads/protected/.* /index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* /index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^config/.* /index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vendor/.* /index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* /index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* /index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/temp/.* /index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* /index.php [L,NC]

##
## White listed folders and files
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.map
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpeg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.gif
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.less
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.scss
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.pdf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.swf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.eot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ttf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.svg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wmv
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.avi
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mov
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.webm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ogg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !docs/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !themes/.*
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

after pasting above configuration in the file save and close and restart apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```